# Checking if file is checked out through CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

Is there a way to check if a file is checked out by another user? I am going trhough a list file by file and would like to avoid the "file is opened by another user" error. Something like this would be nice:

```
Guid id = new Guid(slideLibrary); // ID of Slide-Library.
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetById(id);
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items); // Loading all the fields
System.Security.SecureString pwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char c in "pwd".ToCharArray()) pwd.AppendChar(c);

ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, pwd);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

// Iterating through all the entries.
foreach (var item in items)
{
    String currentID = item["ID"].ToString(); // Getting the ID of the current item.

    if (!item.IsCheckedOut()) // This is the part I am looking for.
    {
       // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Item is blocked, skipping it.")
    }
}
```

I have yet not been able to find something fitting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not get it from `ListItem` but you can get it from `ListItem.File`. For example

```
if(item.File.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None){
// Do stuff...
}
```

To use this code, you need to load the File along with the item. I mean

```
ctx.Load(items, item=> item.Include(f => f.File));
```

Comment: Loading the file in the way you described doesn't work for me. I get a compiler error on ìtem.File` that this does not exist for ListItemCollections. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are right! Check my update